# Need help getting git bash terminal set up to run python

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, git-bash

I am setting up git bash to run python commands in python, however, I keep getting the following error when trying to run

```
bash: python: command not found
```

I reinstalled python and pip to see if this would help but it is still not recognizing it. I have done some research and think it may be a path error but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is it possible you're running `python`when you need to run `python3`?

Answer (score 0):

This error may arise when you haven't selected the option add to path while installing python for this you need to check if your python is edited in system variable

```
My computer -> Properties(by clicking right button) -> Change setting -> Advance setting -> environment variable
```

You must see user variable for *Account Name*

In Environment Variables find Path and click edit

```
Environment Variables -> Path -> Click Edit
```

And check whether there is python path or not
If you cannot find that path, Then go to your C: drive

```
C: -> User -> *Your account* -> App Data
```

This folder may be hidden so show that folder for that you need to go to

```
View -> un-click hidden items
```

Again go to App Data

```
App -> Local -> Programs -> Python
```

Copy this path
Again go to the Environment variable

```
Environment Varaible -> New -> Paste the python path
```